# How can I open the A TAB at 768px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I apologize first, my English is not very good, but I will try to describe my problem.

I'm implementing an RWD effect, and this is it!
When the screen is below 768px, I want to wrap an A tag around the demo block to make the whole block clickable, but when the screen resolution is above 768px, I want to add an A tag to cover the demo block.

I have tried using display:none in the initial a tag;

```css
.demo{
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding:20px;
}
a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#222;
}
.link{
  display: none;
}

@media(max-width:768px){
  .link{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="#">
    <div class="demo">
          <h1><object><a href="javascript:;">我是標題</a></object></h1>
          <p>
            <object><a href="javascript:;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab voluptatum v</a></object>       
         </p>
    </div>
</a>
```

However, this will cause the whole picture to disappear at the beginning, which is not the effect I want. I would like to ask you how to write this better?

```css
.demo{
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding:20px;
}
a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#222;
}
.link{
  display: none;
}

@media(max-width:768px){
  .link{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="#">
    <div class="demo">
          <h1><object><a href="javascript:;">我是標題</a></object></h1>
          <p>
            <object><a href="javascript:;">9999999999999999</a></object>       
         </p>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is only a workaround**

Do not use `display: none;`.
Instead write:

```css
...

.link{
  display: block;
  cursor: default;
}

@media(max-width:768px){
  .link{
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

This will make the mouse cursor appear normal in desktop and appear clickable on mobile.
In reality you can still click, but 99+% of visitors will not realize or attempt to check.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Comment: Thank you, I didn't expect to be able to use this method! Thank you so much!